# Why define struct in variable?

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

Consider the following program:

Many people when they want to use a struct, they create a new variable as:

```
struct structureName variableName
```

While it works when you just define it as:

```
 structureName variableName
```

My teacher always uses the first method. My question is how do they differ? Do I ever need to specify struct before defining my variableName. Here is an example to explain my question:

```
struct example {
    int n;
    char c;
};

int main() {
    example o;
    o.c = 'c';
    o.n = 5;
    printf("%c", o.c);
    printf("%d\n", o.n); //this works

    struct example ex; // this versus "example o" without using struct keyword
    ex.c = 'e';
    ex.n = 7;
    printf("%c", ex.c);
    printf("%d", ex.n); //this works

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you compile it as C++.  Try to compile it as plain C and it will never compile.

Comment: "My teacher always uses the first method" - maybe your teacher is a C guy, and not a C++ guy?

Comment: Is this a class in C? or C++?  Given the rest of the code (printf), I would assume C.  And while some code may be able to be compiled by a C++ compiler, that does not mean that it is valid C code even though it looks like it would be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of the differences between C and C++.

In C, structure names are completely separate from other names and you must use the `struct` keyword to tell the compiler to look for the name of a structure.
Another way to put it is that the `struct` keyword is actually part of the name of the structure.

When designing C++, this was changed and the use of the `struct` (or `class`) keyword was made optional when referring to a structure or class.

Comment: As a side note, I always prefer `typedef`ing my types before including headers.